# How should I use locust to write stress tests for WebSocket

Tags: websocket, stress-testing, locust

1.how should i keep-alive?
2.How to calculate the response time?

I rewrote loust according to online blog

```
class WebSocketClient(object):

    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()

    def connect(self, burl, name):
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            self.conn = self.ws.connect(url=burl)
        except websocket.WebSocketTimeoutException as e:
            total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
            events.request_failure.fire(request_type="websocket", name=name+"_error", response_time=total_time, exception=e)
            flag = False
            return flag
        else:
            total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
            events.request_success.fire(request_type="websocket", name=name+"_right", response_time=total_time, response_length=0)

        return self.conn

    def recv(self):
        return self.ws.recv()

    def send(self, msg):

        self.ws.send(msg)

    def close(self):
        self.ws.close()
class WebsocketLocust(Locust):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WebsocketLocust, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = WebSocketClient(self.host)

class SearchTest(TaskSet):

    @task
    def searchtest(self):
        self.url = 'wss://api.bbxapp.vip/v1/ifcontract/realTime'
        self.client.connect(self.url, name='chat_room')
        flag = True
        while flag:
            data ={"action":"ping"}
            data =json.dumps(data)
            self.client.send(data)
            globals = {'true': 0}
            recv = self.client.recv()
            recv=json.loads(recv)

            if recv["data"]== "pong":
                self.client.send(data)
            else:
                flag = False
```

**Output:**

```
Name                 # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
chat_room_right           1     0(0.00%)    3089    3089    3089  |    3100    0.00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                    1     0(0.00%)                                       0.00
```

the avg time is so long，I think that `"total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)"`  have a few mistakes.

please help me